# Cannot access onTimeSet method in TimePickerDialog

Tags: android

I am trying to get time from timepicker in a FragmentActivity. For this reason I create a class named `TimePickerFragment`. this is the class:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment  {

    public static TimePickerFragment newInstance() {
        return new TimePickerFragment();
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
    public void setListener(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

And this is my Fragmnet activity:

```
public class CreateClass extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener  {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_create_class, container, false);
    //findingbyid

    TimePickerFragment.newInstance().setListener(this);
    starttime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment timepicker = new TimePickerFragment();
            timepicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "time picker");
            flag = 1;
        }
    });
    endtime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment timepicker = new TimePickerFragment();
            timepicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "time picker");
            flag = 2;
        }
    });
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    int h = hourOfDay;
    int m = minute;
    Displaytime(h, m);
}

public void Displaytime(int h, int m) {
    if(flag == 1){
        if(h>12){
            stimeedit.setText(String.valueOf(h-12)+":"+(String.valueOf(m)+" pm"));
        }else if (h==12){
            stimeedit.setText("12:"+(String.valueOf(m)+" pm"));
        }else if (h<12){
            if(h!=0){
                stimeedit.setText(String.valueOf(h)+":"+(String.valueOf(m)+" am"));
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 2){
        if(h>12){
            etimeedit.setText(String.valueOf(h-12)+":"+(String.valueOf(m)+" pm"));
        }else if (h==12){
            etimeedit.setText("12:"+(String.valueOf(m)+" pm"));
        }else if (h<12){
            if(h!=0){
                etimeedit.setText(String.valueOf(h)+":"+(String.valueOf(m)+" am"));
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

with this code, after pressing the button timepickerFragment is showing and I can choose time but the time doesn't set in edittext. if i set any value in edittext in onclicklister method that perfectly works. I am giving an example:

```
 starttime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DialogFragment timepicker = new TimePickerFragment();
        timepicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "time picker");
        stimeedit.settext("hello");
    }
});
```

in stimeedit, "hello" is set perfectly. please, can anyone tell me, how can I add time in edittext.

Comment: You need to call `setListener(CreateClass.this)` on `timepicker` in the `onClick()` methods. The `TimePickerFragment.newInstance().setListener(this)` call you have in `onCreateView()` isn't really doing anything. Also, you'll want to declare them as `TimePickerFragment`, not just `DialogFragment`.

Comment: i write `TimePickerFragment.newInstance().setListener(CreateClass.this);`  in onClicklistener, but nothing changed.

Comment: Yes, because `TimePickerFragment.newInstance()` returns a different instance than `new TimePickerFragment()`. You need to call `setListener()` on the same instance that you're calling `show()` on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the listener on the same instance that gets displayed. They are 2 different objects

```
TimePickerFragment.newInstance().setListener(this);
```

This is the first instance which has the listener but is not displayed on screen. That is why you are not receiving any callbacks.

```
starttime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DialogFragment timepicker = new TimePickerFragment();
        timepicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "time picker");
        flag = 1;
    }
});
endtime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DialogFragment timepicker = new TimePickerFragment();
        timepicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "time picker");
        flag = 2;
    }
});
```

And here you have two other instances which you want to listen to.

Comment: I cant understand! will you please explain with code? actually i'm new in android studio.